# Equations: \Bigg[ not compiling around three conditions as I'd imagine. Alternative to \Bigg[?

Tags: equations, amsmath, amssymb

How can I place the three conditions aligned within the curly brackets, sum and square brackets?

I want this:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
    \max_{r_1 < r_j < r_2 } \begin{cases} \sum_{r=1}^{r_j-r_1} \Bigg[ 1 & if \quad xyz\\ 
    -1 & if \quad abz\\
    0 & if \quad blah \Bigg] - somethinig \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

What should I use instead of `\Bigg[` and `\Bigg]`?

Am I using the wrong packages and/or what is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I compile this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\max_{r_1<r_j<r_2}\left\{\sum_{r=1}^{r_j-r_1}
    \left[\begin{array}{cl}
      1&\text{if }xyz\\
      -1&\text{if abz}\\
      0&\text{if blah}
    \end{array}\right]\quad\text{---}\quad\text{something}\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

then I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is what you're after, or something like it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \max_{r_1 < r_j < r_2 } \left\{
    \sum_{r = 1}^{r_j - r_1} \left[
      \begin{array}{ @{} r l @{} }
         1 & \text{if $xyz$} \\ 
        -1 & \text{if $abz$} \\
         0 & \text{if blah}
      \end{array}
    \right] - \text{something}
  \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

You've mixed in the brackets on a by-row basis, when it should be outside the expression in order to span across it vertically. My approach uses `\left`...`\right` instead, since the content to stretch the fences around is large enough.